# Mock Method Failing due to NULL

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I'm having a problem where a method on my System Under Test is failing due to a NULL reference exception. I can see where the issue lies but I'm not sure as to how to fix it.

The class that I'm testing, in brief, is as follows:

```
public class PaymentService
{
        public PaymentService(ICompanyService companyService,  //Other dependencies)
       {
            _companyService = companyService;
            //Other dependencies being assigned
       }

        public string SetupPayment(User user, ProductVariant product, 
                                   string successUrl, string failureUrl, 
                                   string cancelUrl, string errorUrl)
       {
           var company = _companyService.GetCompanyById(user.GetAppointment().RegistrationNumber);
       }
}
```

The `PaymentService` class has many other interactions but for the sake of this problem, this is all that matters.

As you can see, to call the `GetCompanyId` method within the `CompanyService`, the paramter being passed in of `user.GetAppointment().RegistrationNumber` needs to be satisfied. The implementation for `User.GetAppointment` is as follows:

```
    public Appointment GetAppointment()
    {
        // Check if user has any appointments
        if (Appointments == null || Appointments.Count == 0) return null;
        return Appointments.First().Appointment;
    }
```

Within my unit test, I am now trying to test the `SetupPayment` method but every time it runs, it fails at the point of which it runs the `user.GetAppointment` method as it always returns `null`.

My mocking framework within the unit test has been set up like so (drawing attention to the mocking of the `_companyService`:

```
var companyServiceMock = new Mock<ICompanyService>();

        companyServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetCompanyByRegistrationNumber(It.IsAny<string>()))
        .Returns(new Company()
        {
            RegistrationNumber = "12333",
        });

_paymentService = new PaymentService(_companyService, _accountService, _settings, _settingsHelper, _scheduleManagerService, _appSettingService);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `User` has no `Appointments`, so `GetAppointment` return `null`. When you create the `User`, can you setup the `Appointments`? If not, I would recommend, adding an interface - `IUser` let's say - to the `User` class and passing that in instead, that way you can passing a mock of `IUser` and mock the method `GetAppointment`.

Comment: Dam, I had a feeling I'd get the answer of having to create an interface for the `User`. I can see why people speak of test induced design damage now :(

Comment: @Stu1986C As I mentioned, alternatively, you could setup the `Appointments` property in your test.

Comment: Yeh, I think I may have to. I'll let you know how I get on. Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: It did the job. Thanks @TomDoesCode :)